# case insensitive xpath queries in php for tag names

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Say I have an XML file with `<tag>...</tag>`. I want to be able to query the tag name without regard for case. eg. I want to get `<tag>` tags, `<TAG>` tags, etc.

`$dom->getElementByTagName()` is case-sensitive. It also seems to me that XPath is as well. I tried `$xpath->query("translate(//a, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')")` and `$xpath->query("lower-case(//a)")` both to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: XML is case-sensitive and so is XPath. If you want to match element names without case sensitivity you can do it with constructs like `//*[translate(local-name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'tag']`, but if you need to do this then you are seriously abusing XML and seriously making your life difficult.

Comment: I just want a parser that's error tolerant lol.